# Duplicate result for NATIVE_APP and WEBVIEW_chrome

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automation, webview, appium

*Why am I getting the [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_chrome] on two lines?
(As a result, the login field gets populated twice)*

```
WebElement LoginButton = driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
LoginButton.click();

Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String context : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextNames);
```

I'm getting the following:

> [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_chrome]
> [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Print `context` and not `contextNames` as below,

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String context : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(context);
}
```